# IP long string filter

Tags: php, ip, postman

**Hey,**

i am trying to only show 1 bit of the long string i get from the api i got fram postman, the only thing i need to show is the city. How do i need do this?

i'm trying to find a way with php but i have no clue what to do

```
a:14:{s:10:"regionName";s:10:"California";s:6:"status";s:7:"success";s:4:"city";s:13:"Mountain View";s:8:"timezone";s:19:"America/Los_Angeles";s:7:"country";s:13:"United States";s:11:"countryCode";s:2:"US";s:3:"zip";s:0:"";s:3:"lon";d:-122.08499908447266;s:3:"isp";s:6:"Google";s:2:"as";s:19:"AS15169 Google Inc.";s:5:"query";s:7:"8.8.8.8";s:6:"region";s:2:"CA";s:3:"lat";d:37.42290115356445;s:3:"org";s:6:"Google";}
```

(im using the ip of google just for this question)

so the length of the city name changes!

the site where i got it frm http://ip-api.com/php/8.8.8.8
and the code i am using:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://ip-api.com/php/8.8.8.8",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "postman-token: 2e83e542-a6fb-5bb6-94e0-c1908282a2a2"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

Comment: What is this? A string, json, .. ?

Comment: That's a string that's a result of a `serialize` call. You can do `unserialize` to get the original data

Comment: its from curl, this is where i got it from http://ip-api.com/php/8.8.8.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a product of running a PHP variable in a PHP [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) you can reverse it with [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://ip-api.com/php/8.8.8.8",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "postman-token: 2e83e542-a6fb-5bb6-94e0-c1908282a2a2"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
$responseArray = unserialize($response); //You probably need some error trapping here

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $responseArray["country"];
}
```